# I am looking to rank search results in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, search, ranking

The query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 t.columns
FROM dbo.teams as t
RIGHT JOIN fnParseString('Nugget,Tulsa',',') ps ON t.team_name LIKE '%'+ps.string+'%' OR t.nickname LIKE '%'+ps.string+'%'
```

This does return the results I want, but but the ordering isn't useful.

I may add more columns to the search.

How do I rank the rows based on accuracy and number of matched terms? I know it only needs to match one of the terms to be selected, is there a way to then count the number of terms that match the columns.

I see [Need help with SQL for ranking search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075026/need-help-with-sql-for-ranking-search-results) but will the subselect work for an arbitrary number of search tokens

Comment: You could add something like this to the select... `case when t.team_name LIKE '%'+ps.string+'%' then 1 else 0 + case when t.nickname LIKE '%'+ps.string+'%' then 1 else 0 end as Rank`

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to some dynamic SQL

```
Declare @SearchFor  varchar(max) ='Daily,Production,default'  -- Any comma delim string
Declare @SearchFrom varchar(150) ='OD'                        -- table or even a join statemtn
Declare @SearchExpr varchar(150) ='[OD-Title]'                -- Any field or even expression
Declare @ReturnCols varchar(150) ='[OD-Nr],[OD-Title]'        -- Any field(s) even with alias 

Set @SearchFor = 'Sign(CharIndex('''+Replace(Replace(Replace(@SearchFor,' , ',','),', ',''),',',''','+@SearchExpr+'))+Sign(CharIndex(''')+''','+@SearchExpr+'))'
Declare @SQL nvarchar(Max) = 'Select * from (Select Distinct'+@ReturnCols+',Hits='+@SearchFor+' From '+@SearchFrom + ') A Where Hits>0 Order by Hits Desc' 

Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

```
OD-Nr   OD-Title                    Hits
3       Daily Production Summary    2
6       Default Settings            1
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-dynamic option, for contrast.  You'd have to add to the order by and the join as you add more columns to check.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 t.columns
FROM dbo.teams as t
RIGHT JOIN fnParseString('Nugget,Tulsa',',') ps 
    ON t.team_name LIKE '%'+ps.string+'%' 
       OR t.nickname LIKE '%'+ps.string+'%'
order by 
    case when t.team_name LIKE '%'+ps.string+'%' then 1 else 0 + 
    case when t.nickname LIKE '%'+ps.string+'%' then 1 else 0 
    desc
```